# Using Vetiver in R, why am I getting a metric_set error when trying to run compute_metrics() for a classification model?

Tags: r, vetiver

I am relatively new to using Vetiver with RStudio and I am trying to plot some accuracy metrics. I am using the metrics: accuracy and kap but when I pass in all the parameters into compute_metrics I get this error, [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3pei.png).

I ran the demo code on the Vetiver site and was following a similar procedure modifying it for a classification model instead of a regression.

Here is my code below and the original data trained on the vetiver model doesn't have a timestamp. It was added for newData1 which is passed into my vetiver model for monitoring. The timestamps are produced to simulate adding new data to the model over time.

```
library(parsnip)
library(recipes)
library(workflows)
library(tidyverse)
data(bivariate, package = "modeldata")
bivariate_train

biv_rec <-
  recipe(Class ~ ., data = bivariate_train) %>%
  step_BoxCox(all_predictors())%>%
  step_normalize(all_predictors())

svm_spec <-
  svm_linear(mode = "classification") %>%
  set_engine("LiblineaR")

svm_fit <- 
  workflow(biv_rec, svm_spec) %>%
  fit(sample_frac(bivariate_train, 0.7))

library(vetiver)

v <- vetiver_model(svm_fit, "biv_svm")
v

library(pins)
model_board <- board_temp(versioned = TRUE)
model_board %>% vetiver_pin_write(v)

svm_fit <- 
  workflow(biv_rec, svm_spec) %>%
  fit(sample_frac(bivariate_train, 0.7))

v <- vetiver_model(svm_fit, "biv_svm")

model_board %>% vetiver_pin_write(v)

model_board %>% pin_versions("biv_svm")

library(plumber)
pr() %>%
  vetiver_api(v)

vetiver_write_plumber(model_board, "biv_svm")

bivariate_val

#Add datestamp to validation data
values = seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-01"), to = as.Date("2021-10-27"), by = 'day')
# ValDate <- merge(bivariate_val, values)
bivariate_val$date_obs <- values

newData1 <- bivariate_val[1:150,]
Data2 <- bivariate_val[151:300,]

class_metrics_T <- metric_set(accuracy, kap)
original_metrics <-
  augment(v,new_data = newData1) %>%
  vetiver_compute_metrics(date_obs,"week",Class,class_metrics_T)
```

This is a sample of newData1, I am trying to predict the class as either one or two based on 2 features A,B.
[Dataset to add for computing metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5MYr.png)

Also don't know if this adds any value, but my class column for predicting is of type factor(fct)

Answer (score 0):

I made a bit of a smaller example to show you what may have gone wrong:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidymodels)
data(bivariate, package = "modeldata")
monitoring <- bivariate_val %>% mutate(date = lubridate::today() + 299)
glm_fit <- 
    workflow(
        Class ~ .,
        logistic_reg()
    ) %>% fit(bivariate_train)

library(vetiver)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'vetiver'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tune':
#> 
#>     load_pkgs
v <- vetiver_model(glm_fit, "two-classes")

augment(v, new_data = monitoring) %>%
    vetiver_compute_metrics(
        date, 
        "week", 
        Class, 
        .pred_class, 
        metric_set = yardstick::metric_set(accuracy, kap)
    )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   .index        .n .metric  .estimator .estimate
#>   <date>     <int> <chr>    <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 2023-10-04   300 accuracy binary         0.747
#> 2 2023-10-04   300 kap      binary         0.415
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

When you [call `vetiver_compute_metrics()`](https://rstudio.github.io/vetiver-r/reference/vetiver_compute_metrics.html) you need to pass in both `truth` and `estimate`. I think for your example it would be `Class` and `.pred_class`, the same as mine.